# Rewritten expression calls operator method ... but the original node had no operator method

Tags: c#, expression-trees, linq-expressions

I'm trying to change a part of an expression tree, where a property X of type MyEnum is compared to some value x:

```
$model.X == .Constant<MyEnum>(x)
```

I want to modify the tree to substitute the comparison to compare a property Y of type `Guid` with a value y (which will be derived from x).

```
$model.Y == .Constant<Guid>(y)
```

So I've inherited from `ExpressionVisitor` and I've overridden `VisitMember` to substitute Y for X, and I've overridden `VisitConstant` to substitute y for x.

Running this yields the following `InvalidOperationException`:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Rewritten expression calls operator method 'Boolean op_Equality(System.Guid, System.Guid)', but the original node had no operator method. If this is is intentional, override 'VisitBinary' and change it to allow this rewrite.

My main question is: what do I have to do in `VisitBinary`? And my side question is: why is the exception message telling that the original node had no operator method. I think this is not true. It didn't have `op_Equality(System.Guid, System.Guid)` for sure but it had the equality operator for the MyEnum type, I assume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing from the name that `MyEnum` is some sort of `Enum` type.

`Enum` types don't need operator methods, because CIL handles equality comparisons for them directly (the same is also true of the built-in integral, floating-point and boolean types).

There's no way to change the method through `BinaryExression.Update()` (which will be called either explicitly in your visitor or implicitly because your visitor has changed one or both of the left and right expressions, and that's the default behaviour in that case) you will have to have `VisitBinary()` create and return a new `BinaryExpression` through the appropriate call to `Expression.Equal()`.

Comment: Overriding VisitBinary is the better choice in any case because it puts all the logic in one place. I wonder how the OPs code must look like before doing that, probably convoluted with instance state carried across VisitC calls. In VisitBinary, he can just inspect the two children and if matched perform the rewrite. +1

Comment: That's a very interesting insight. I didn't know that the Expression classes already incorporate CIL "knowledge" even before they're compiled.

Comment: Its more the factory method that does so than the instance itself. It's worth noting that if you'd started with a binary expression with a different operator method then the update would still have failed but with a different exception, so the implementation detail affects the nature of the exception (which is perhaps still not ideal) but not whether it happens.